# Android studio cannot resolve symbol after R.xxx

Tags: android

I am using android studio 2.1.2
studio not resolving symbol like id,layout,mipmap,anim ..

I have tried Invalidate cache/restart , sync project with gradle, clean project, rebuild project but none of above working please help me..

Screenshot:[image]

this are my imports

```
    import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.GradientDrawable;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.animation.AlphaAnimation;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
```

event log

```
2:17:33 AM Gradle sync started
2:18:00 AM Gradle sync completed
2:18:01 AM Executing tasks: [:app:generateDebugSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar, :app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources]
2:18:10 AM Gradle build finished in 10s 125ms
2:20:46 AM Executing tasks: [:app:clean, :app:generateDebugSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar, :app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:assembleDebug]
2:22:06 AM Gradle build finished with 66 error(s) in 1m 20s 297ms
2:23:16 AM Gradle sync started
2:23:38 AM Gradle sync completed
2:23:49 AM Executing tasks: [:app:generateDebugSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar, :app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources]
2:24:52 AM Gradle build finished in 1m 12s 945ms
```

Comment: what do the imports for the activity look like? What xml files do you have, do any have any syntax errors? (this stops R being generated)

Comment: i have added imports

Comment: do you see at the bottom right, you have 3 errors in your event log. What are they?

Comment: added it its about upde and 66 errors of id;

Comment: you might want to find and fix those 66 errors? :D

Comment: they all are like above screen it contains ids, anim,layout,midmap etc

Comment: any syntax error inside the XML files stopes the R file being generated, so at least one of those 66 errors is hopefully not in above activity

Comment: ok thanks i am searching...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't belive it i have defined int R and it causes error i have removed it problrm solved you know why thank you guys for being kind!!!!